# Group comma-separated repeated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with these values

```
SITE_NAME | CATEGORY |
----------------------
SITE1 | CAR, TRAVEL
SITE2 | TRAVEL
SITE3 | SPORT, GAME
SITE4 | GAME
SITE5 | CAR
SITE6 | TRAVEL
SITE7 | GAME
```

I wanted it to aggregate values repeated so I am using this:

```
SELECT category, COUNT (*) FROM table_db group by category having count (*)> = 1
```

This works in grouping equal 'category' values, but treats 'CAR, TRAVEL' as a value other than 'CAR' I wanted it to be also identified as a repeated value.

This code displays this:

```
CAR, TRAVEL
TRAVEL
SPORT, GAME
CAR
GAME
```

I wanted it to look like this:

```
CAR
TRAVEL
SPORT
GAME
```

Comment: You really should change your original table design. NEVER store multiple values in a single column!!!!

Comment: This schema is a blatant violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of 
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you adjusted it to have some kind of proper normal form this would be trivial.

Comment: I can not re-design the database. I want to do the explained in the post.

Comment: Do you have a table that lists all categories one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I totally agree with the other comments about database design, if, for whatever reason, you are stuck with the design you have, then you need to create yourself a split function.  Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.fnsplit(
    IN stringlist character varying,
    IN delimit character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(items character varying) AS
$BODY$
declare remainderlist character varying;
declare front character varying;
declare delimitpos integer;
begin
    drop table if exists tmptbl;
    create temp table tmptbl(items character varying);
    remainderlist := $1;
    delimitpos := strpos(remainderlist, $2);
    while delimitpos > 0 loop
        front := trim(both from(left(remainderlist, delimitpos -1)));
        remainderlist := substr(remainderlist, delimitpos + 1);
        if length(front) > 0 then
            insert into tmptbl values (front);
        end if;
        delimitpos := strpos(remainderlist, $2);
    end loop;
    --insert last value
    remainderlist := trim(both from remainderlist);
    if length(remainderlist) > 0 then
        insert into tmptbl values (remainderlist);
    end if;
    return query
        select * from tmptbl;
        return;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

You would then be able to use it in your select like this:

```
SELECT category, COUNT (*) FROM
(SELECT fnsplit(category, ', ') as category FROM table_db) d
group by category having count(*) >= 1;
```

I cannot help stressing though, that this should be a last resort!

EDIT

It has been pointed out that the OP wants MySQL.  This is a bit trickier, because MySQL does not allow functions to return a table.  So you have to use temporary tables instead.  So now the function looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE fnsplit(
    stringlist varchar(2000),
    delimit varchar(20)
) 
BEGIN

declare remainderlist varchar(2000);
declare front varchar(2000);
declare delimitpos integer;

    SET remainderlist = stringlist;
    SET delimitpos = position(delimit in remainderlist);
    while delimitpos > 0 do
        SET front = trim(both from(left(remainderlist, delimitpos -1)));
        SET remainderlist = substr(remainderlist, delimitpos + 1);
        if length(front) > 0 then
            insert into tblTmpSplit values (front);
        end if;
        SET delimitpos = position(delimit in remainderlist);
    end while;
    SET remainderlist = trim(both from remainderlist);
    if length(remainderlist) > 0 then
        insert into tblTmpSplit values (remainderlist);
    end if;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can now call it like this:

```
SET @allcategories = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(category separator ', ') FROM table_db);

drop table if exists tbltmpsplit;
create temporary table tbltmpsplit(items varchar(2000));

call fnsplit(@allcategories, ', ');

SELECT *, Count(*) FROM tbltmpsplit GROUP BY items having count(*) >= 1;

drop table if exists tbltmpsplit;
```

This returns:

```
CAR 2
GAME    3
SPORT   1
TRAVEL  3
```